# UIViewController has no member hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, swift3, uicontainerview

I suddenly started getting this compiler error. It was fine yesterday! (iOS 10.2)

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed'

Setting this `segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` inside `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

UPDATE: It only happens when running on a simulator. It's fine on an actual device.

Comment: Which iOS version you are talking about?

Comment: @Varun iOS 10.2

Comment: Add check condition for avoiding error:
           `if (segue.destination.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed))) {
                // Call hidesBottomBarWhenPushed in here
            }`

Answer (score 0):

> Value of type 'XXX' has no member 'XXX'

You get above Swift compiler error message when calling a method or setting a value of a property which doesn't exist.

**Examples**

```
/* Static members */
UIViewController.thisPropertyDoesntExist = true

UIViewController.thisMethodDoesntExist()

/* Instance members */
let vc = UIViewController()

vc.thisPropertyDoesntExist = true

vc.thisMethodDoesntExist()
```

**Solution**

Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder and Re-build the app